# Sockets - Connect two computers on the same network with no port forwarding?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip

I am very confused. I cannot find a specific answer to my conundrum.
I figured this applies to all languages, but I'm writing my application in Java specifically.

So, I am simply trying to connect two separate computers, which are running on the **SAME** network.

Computer 'A' is the server, and Computer 'B' is the client.

When the Client connects, I just want to display a message on the server.

**My question:**
Is it possible to connect two PC's (one being the server, the other being the client), on the same network, without any kind of port forwarding, or other internet settings (with the exception of some firewall settings)? Also, what IP do you have to use to connect the two PC's?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You only need port forwarding *between* networks, and not always then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need port forwarding.  All you need to do on the server is something like

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(KNOWN_PORT);
while(running) {
    executor.submit(new SocketHandler(ss.accept()));
```

On the client side

```
Socket s = new Socket(KNOWN_HOST, KNOWN_PORT);
```

Comment: Awesome, what would I have to use as the IP though if it's two computers on the same network??
localhost??

Comment: You need to use the IP of the server when connecting the client. I suggest you find a primer series on IP networks and read it.

Comment: You need to know the host name of the host you are trying to connect to.  You can use either it's IP address for it's configured DNS name or add an entry in the hosts file of the client.

Comment: I will look into it Eric, thanks. But I just need a simple answer, External IP, localhost...? "The IP of the server" doesn't really help, as I don't know what the "IP of the server" is.

Comment: @user1869353 The IP address is like a street address. And the port like a street number.  The house might have the number on it, but unless you also know the street, your only option is to go to every street and check that number.  BTW There are 4 billion possible IPv4 address (or streets) to check.

Comment: If you assume the other machine is on the same subnet, you might only need to try 255 addresses.  This can be done by polling each one and is a typical hacking technique.

Comment: Log into each machine and type "ipconfig" or "ifconfig" on the command line. It will output the IP address of the machine. Then use that in the application.

Comment: @Zagrev Of course, you need to know the host names to try this. ;)

Comment: No, you only need physical access. :>

Comment: I used my Default Gateway address (192.168.ect...), and I get a connection refused error on my client, but that's another subject. I'll try my 225 address later, I'm out right now so I can't test anything at the moment. @Zagrev When you say your "physical IP", are we talking an external IP (physical IP, WAN address, *insert other terminology here*...)?

Comment: ipconfig will give you output something like this:
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bd3d:447d:bc4e:db38%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.110
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

You want the IPv4 address

Comment: @Zagrev Awesome, IPv4 is what I was looking for. Thanks everybody.